# onClick not working properly after upgrading to compileSdkVersion 30

Tags: android, android-studio, onclicklistener, android-11

I had my project at 29 sdk version and it was perfectly working, but I decided to upgrade to 30 and also my libraries and gradle, these are some of the major upgrades I did:

1. gradle-7.0.2
2. com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1
3. androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0
4. androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0

I fixed some deprecated code (mostly using the new startActivityForResult flow)

But here's my problem, after that all my click listener are not working properly, for example I have this view structure: LinearLayout -> TextView. I have an onclick event on the LinearLayout but the click event only goes through if I click the borders of the linearlayout and not on top of the textview, if I click the textview nothing happens, but this is happening for every single onclick in my project, this worked perfectly before, is this now a new feature in adroid? How to I disable this?

This is the example view, it's part of a horizontal recyclerView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/card_rca"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:textColor="@color/lightGray"
        android:id="@+id/text_category"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the click listener

```
categoryContainer.setOnClickListener {
    // do some filtering ...
}
```

Things I've tried:
Adding to the textView

```
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
android:textIsSelectable="false"
```

But I just don't get it, why is it doing that now? Any insights of why this is happening? Anyone experiencing the same things?

Thanks

Comment: Could you show your onclick listener java code

Comment: @lyncx sure, here it is: I'll add it to the description of the question as well: categoryContainer.setOnClickListener {
            //do some filtering in recycler
        }

Comment: I just tried the above code and it is working for me at api 30. Just added textview clickable as false. Im assuming categoryContainer is reference to the linear layout? You could add `android:longClickable="false"` as well and see it.

Comment: @Sepak you got any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

because the onClick attributes its deprecated in Api 31 and then use `onClickListener`
constructor instead of this attr XML
first add id in textView or Button in Ur XML layout root tag element
and then initialize it in related activity with `findViewById` then write the object
about text or button with onClickListener for example:

`Button` mBtn;

and then onCreate method body:

```
mBtn = findViewById(// your id button tag);

mBtn.onClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

 @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // do your work
            } 

});
```